# Forwarding posts from a private channel of Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a invite link of private channel, and I wanna forwards (or delivery) posts from this channel to me. My desired pseudo code is like below.

```
def get_channel(bot, update):
   message=update.channel_post.text
   print(message)

updater = Updater(my_token)
channel_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, get_channel, 
channel_post_updates=True, invite_link='http://t.me/aa23faba22939bf')
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(channel_handler)
```

This works well when my bot is in the channel which I created(invite_link is added for my purpose. I don't know where invite_link should be input). But what I want is that my bot forwards posts from channel in which my bot is 'not' included. I prefer python, but any API will be ok. I searched all the google world but have no clues.. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Are your bot admin?

Comment: Sean/ Yes of course I am the admin of bot. And I found a solution in telethon API : target_channel = client.get_entity(' invite link after t.me '), the remained problem is that I should extract messages from entity 'target_channel'.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with Telethon library. It works for me(http://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/advanced-usage/update-modes.html)

```
def callback(update):
    print('I received', update)

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash,
                        update_workers=1, spawn_read_thread=False)

client.connect()
client.add_event_handler(callback)
client.idle()  # ends with Ctrl+C
```

In callback function you can filter only channel posts or group messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to forward message (of any kind) from channel (doesn't matter if it's private or public) to any other chat:

1. add your bot to channel (notes that, bots are only added as an admin to channel and have admin privileges)
2. following code (in python) will do the Forwarding:

   ```
    from telegram import Bot
    def forward(update, context):
        chat_id = update.effective_chat.id

        bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
        bot.forward_message(chat_id = chat_id,
                            from_chat_id = channel_id,
                            message_id = (number))
   ```

   the above code, will forward message from 'from_chat_id' to 'chat_id' (is the user's chat_id which ask the query)
3. channel_id is just simply the channel's telegram invite link (which start with @)
4. message_id is the unique number of the message which is in the channel. If you right-click on the message inside the channel, and select 'Copy Post Link' and paste it somewhere, is something like this:
   https://t.me/c/123456789/2040

   (123456789 is the link of private channel. If this was a public channel, instead of '123456789', there was channel's public address which starts with @)
5. the message id is: 2040, not the whole.

refrence: https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.forward_message